# Oracle DB Table to SQL Server DB Table

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle

I am wondering if there is a way to replicate an oracle table over to a sql server table. Both servers are on the same network. I would like to have this automated perhaps using a stored procedure on the sql instance. Is there any way to do this automatically? Or can anyone point me to a good sql script to connect to an oracle db server and export a table file?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an Oracle linked server on SQL-Server. In this way you would use the Oracle data directly from SQL-server.

Take a look at this tutorial: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2013/10/02/creating-a-linked-server-for-oracle-in-64bit-sql-server.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at that and get back to you about if it does what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Import Data function located under Tasks when you right click on a database in SQL Server Management Studio.  It will walk you through picking the Source, the Destination, and how the columns map to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28766

Maybe it should help you